# Integral involving modified bessel function of second kind, exponential and power

Tags: pr.probability, integration, bessel-functions

I need to compute the following integral. 
$$
\int_0^a e^{-bx}\sqrt{4(a-x)}K_1(\sqrt{4(a-x))}dx\,.
$$
where $$ a>0$$
and $b$ can be greater than zero or less than zero but it is not a complex number.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

BR

Frank

Comment: It will be of great help if somebody could point me to some reference where i can find similar kind of problems. Thanks

Comment: there might well be a closed form solution in certain limits of $a,b$ (would that be enough for you?), but not a general solution for any $a,b$.

Comment: Thanks Carlo Beenakker for your interest. Yes that will be excellent. I will be happy to see such a solution.